# Creating a java program that calculates fares for a toll road

Tags: java, logic, pseudocode

I am having a hard time getting started with this program. It is supposed to promped user for vehichle typ, number of miles to be traveled, and whether or not they have an EZ-Pass. then calculate and print vehicle type, number of miles traveled, whether or not they have an EZ-Pass, and the fare collected.
toll road spans 76.4 miles.
Fares for the toll road are calculated based on vehicle type:
Motorcycle – Flat Fee of $1.06
Car - $0.05 per mile
SUV - $0.08 per mile
Truck - $0.14 per mile
Vehicles having an E-ZPass attached to them earn a 10% discount off their fare.

After the user has indicated they wish to exit the program (this is the only way the program should exit), the program will display a report containing a list of each vehicle type and the number of fares collected for that vehicle type, the total number of vehicles, the number of vehicles that used an E-ZPass, and the total fare collected across all vehicles.

I tried using if statements but wasn't happy with the result, maybe for statements fit it better?

Thanks for reading

Comment: What code have you tried? Please post your attempt in the question.

Comment: Where is your code? Please add your code to question so you can get proper help.

Comment: @JClassic  I don't have any code yet, still trying to figure out how to go about the logic of the program. This is new to me and I getting started is the hardest part

Comment: @Dipen_a I don't have any code yet, still trying to figure out how to go about the logic of the program. This is new to me and I getting started is the hardest part

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with a defining diagram that helps you identify the problem you're trying to solve, continuing through the remaining steps of the problem solving process. This will yield a much better result than jumping immediately to coding and posting algorithm questions on Internet forums (which by the way, violates the Honor Code).

Good luck!